# How do I generate a histogram of random numbers?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I generated 100 random numbers between 1 and 100 with code:

```
def histogram():
    for x in range(100):
        x = random.randint(1, 100)
        print(x)
```

Now I am trying to represent this information in a histogram, I imported matplotlib.pyplot as plt and tried to construct this but I seem to be encountering problems.

I tried:

```
def histogram():
    for x in range(100):
        x = random.randint(1, 100)
        return x       
    histogram_plot = histogram()
    plt.hist(histogram_plot)
    plt.show()
```

and I also tried:

```
def histogram():
    for x in range(100):
        x = random.randint(1, 100)
        print(x)
        plt.hist(x)
        plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what are you getting ?

Comment: Putting an unconditional `return` inside a loop means that the function will return after one iteration of the loop. You really don't want that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a small working example that is similar to your code

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import random
>>> data = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)]
>>> plt.hist(data)
(array([ 15.,  13.,   9.,   9.,  11.,   9.,   9.,  11.,   6.,   8.]),
 array([   1. ,   10.9,   20.8,   30.7,   40.6,   50.5,   60.4,   70.3,   80.2,   90.1,  100. ]),
 <a list of 10 Patch objects>)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

The issue you are having is in your `histogram` function. You are re-assigning the variable `x` to a random `int` every iteration, rather than building up a `list` of random values.

Answer (score 1):

In the first function, you `return` in a loop, so the result will never get plotted since the interpreter will never reach the plot code. In you second example you iterate and each time plot a single instance.

Simply create a list of random numbers and plot them:

```
def histogram():
    xs = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)]
    print(x)
    plt.hist(xs)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice example of showing a histogram of Exponentially, Normally and Poisson distributed random numbers.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
np.random.seed(10)

fig, axs=plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 6))
axs[0].hist(np.random.exponential(scale = 10, size = 10000), color = "r")
axs[0].set_title("Exponentially")

axs[1].hist(np.random.randn(10000), color = "m") 
axs[1].set_title("Normally")

axs[2].hist(np.random.poisson(lam = 5, size = 10000), color = "k")
axs[2].set_title("Poisson")

plt.show()
```

[image]